# Geometry node booleon material

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hi any idea to insert color from other booleon object in geometry node.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome ! Two notes : Your image is really low-res around the node tree and it's hard to see exactly what you did there, and 2 : You are using an alpha version which may or may not change in the future so it's hard to answer this question for posterity. That being said, I think you should be able to do it by using a third boolean with Union

Comment: @Gorgious: he wants to apply material ...to this one cut out cube...so a third boolean wouldn't help - i think ;)

Comment: do you mean like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/07KzA.png

Answer (score 2):

you just assign a material as you did before like this:

[image]

result:

[image]